# Error declaring method with Objective-C selector

Tags: swift, xcode7.3

I'm getting this error when I try to declare a method:

[image: no method declared with objective-c selector]

Here's the code:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("itemDroppedOnCharacter:"), name: "onTargetDropped", object: nil)

func itemDroppedOnCharacter(notif: AnyObject) {

    print("Item Dropped On Character")

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the posted code is *different* from that in the screenshot (and therefore causes a different  warning message).

Comment: what's the difference? i don´t see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectors have changed with Xcode 7.3.  You need to explicitly declare the selector that belongs to your class:

```
class MyClass {
    func someFunc() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyClass.itemDroppedOnCharacter(_:)), name: "onTargetDropped", object: nil)
    }

    @objc func itemDroppedOnCharacter(notif: AnyObject) {
        print("Item Dropped On Character")
    }
}
```

You can also have `MyClass` inherit from `NSObject` if you don't want to add `@objc` to expose the selector to Objective-C:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    func someFunc() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyClass.itemDroppedOnCharacter(_:)), name: "onTargetDropped", object: nil)
    }

    func itemDroppedOnCharacter(notif: AnyObject) {
        print("Item Dropped On Character")
    }
}
```